# CSV file Parsing issue because of unintended characters (CParserError: Error tokenizing data) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, codec

I have seen some questions similar to above. being not able to fix, I am asking.

I have a csv, when I opened in text pad, I can clearly see some special characters were appended. And which causes error while using same with pandas (python).
The error details are as below

```css
  1211     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1212         try:
-> 1213             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1214         except StopIteration:
   1215             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:7988)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:8244)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:8970)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\parser.c:8838)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas\parser.c:22649)()

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 5
```

I have used the code below, with multiple options such as to include the encoding etc. nothing seems working.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('D:/code/python/review3.csv')
print(type(data))
print(data)
```

The csv in txt format.

```
ÐÏà¡±á                >  þÿ                9          þÿÿÿ    þÿÿÿ    8   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ     »
Ì       á  °Á    â   \ p 
  Raj Sharad                                                                                                   B  °a   =  œ           c        ¯   ¼   @        =  àZ Ï?N*8      X"       ·   Ú    1  È   ÿ      Arial1  È   ÿ      Arial1  È   ÿ      Arial1  È   ÿ      Arial1  È   ÿ      Arial1  È   ÿ      Arial1  È   ÿ      Arial ¤   Generalà   ¤ õÿ   ô        À à   ¤ õÿ   ô        À à   ¤ õÿ   ô        À à   ¤ õÿ   ô        À à   ¤ õÿ   ô        À à   ¤ õÿ   ô        À à   ¤ õÿ   ô        À à   ¤ õÿ   ô        À à   ¤ õÿ   ô        À à   ¤ õÿ   ô        À à   ¤ õÿ   ô        À à   ¤ õÿ   ô        À à   ¤ õÿ   ô        À à   ¤ õÿ   ô        À à   ¤ õÿ   ô        À à   ¤ õÿ   ô        À à   ¤     ø        À à   ¤     ø        À “  € ÿ`  …  âX     Sheet 1ü   “   r   
  Review_URL  Review  Profile_URL  Name  Age  Gender  HomeTownF  http://www.mouthshut.com/review/HDFC-Life-Insurance-review-npsuqnrlulmH  Last week I did a policy with hdfc life of 30000 per year for 12years then company will pay me 28000 for next 12 years at the end of 24yrs of my plan I will get a huge amount of 300000. So I am happy this plan lets hope for the best. Dont face any fruad and cheat. I also have a account with hdfc bank. Now lets see wt happens
%  http://www.mouthshut.com/arjunsinha80  Arjun Singh  21  Male  KolkataF  http://www.mouthshut.com/review/HDFC-Life-Insurance-review-rlssrtosrlm  I was get Hdfc life insurance few years ago. At  that time they was saying this is the best plan for you according to your income and requirements. I trust on them I get insurance. But few months ago when I visit their office they said tour policy is lapsed because  you not paid premium. I was socked I done all payments on time to their agent. They said you have to pay all that amounts again. I'm very flustered. They are cheater. They must informed me by calls or post about my lapsed policy. Their customers service is not helpful. I don't recommended hdfc life insurance to anyone. Beware from these cheater company and their agents.
  http://www.mouthshut.com/gkamal  Kamal Kumar  RataindaF  http://www.mouthshut.com/review/HDFC-Life-Insurance-review-nptnonosrlmy  HDFC SL Crest is the all time worse policy I have ever seen. Unknowingly I opted for this premium in Oct 2012 and till now I paid 4 installments(100k*4) and now the total fund value is 415k, which is the worse fund performance. If I could have deposited this amount in any bank, I could have got more returns by this time.I sincerely urging to the new policy seekers i.e. do not invest money in this policy, if your money is important to you.Please do not go for HDFC SL Crest policy, even if they assure you 15% max returns because at the end the returns are purely depend on the total number of units and market performance.Shaik
!  http://www.mouthshut.com/bhasha81  jaan Sk  *-*F  http://www.mouthshut.com/review/HDFC-Life-Insurance-review-lptnmroprlm@  MAKEING PEOPLE FOOL.My famliy friend  had a policy of hdfc life . which is term was 6 years after six years  we went to get his money what he  saw and hear was shocking from himsorry sir ur term is 12 years which has more six years to  have . he was shocked and inquriy about the agent  which makes his policy they told him he had left the job. and also the  sum assured was differt  . they are not trustable  . I m  really  sooory to say please do  not waste ur money with them.they only loot and nver give u sum asured by themthanks n be alert about fraud hdfc life agents
  http://www.mouthshut.com/umi123  Umer Ashraf  25  Srinagar, jammu and kashmirF  http://www.mouthshut.com/review/HDFC-Life-Insurance-review-uuqmusnorlmî  Three weeks ago, I purchased a HDFC Life Cancer Care plan through HDFC Life website.  An agent called me for my personal details and I have offered it. Unfortunately, they have captured all my information incorrectly including my PAN number. I have requested them to change it. I have also given a letter to the local branch. Two weeks went  by, no response received. I escalated the issue and sent more than 10 emails over a period of 10 days. No response received. As a final call, I raised the issue with IRDA. As a result of which, they sent me the cancellation form .AdviceDo not buy HDFC Life Products.Call center really sucks.Escalation point of contacts are false. Emails will be undelivered.Customer service executives are un professional.
$  http://www.mouthshut.com/Saravanan_b  Bsarav B  -F  http://www.mouthshut.com/review/HDFC-Life-Insurance-review-msrnqqtnrlm¢  Do not take annuity plan with HDFC. I paid Rs.10006 per annum for 14 years. They promised a return of 7% to 8% PA at the time of taking the policy. The total premium paid between 2002 and 2015 comes to Rs.1.40 Lac. If we assume interest at 1% PA compounded on annual basis, we should get Rs.1.10 Lac(around) in 2016. The total amount receivable at an interest rate of 1% PA hence comes to Rs.2.50 Lac(1.40+1.10). Initially they refused to pay the fund value of Rs.2.24 Lac, agreed to pay annuity of Rs.15000 per annum till my life. When I told them that this amount will earn an annual interest of Rs.22400 even if I place as FDR with reputed corporate, they tried to convince me as if they are giving a great charity.When I threatened them to take up the matter with IRDA in case they refuse to pay my amount, they agreed to pay Rs.2.19 Lac after deducting Rs.0.05 Lac. When I asked as to how they arrive at a sum of Rs.2.24 Lac, they simply said that as per the terms of pension policy, the amount payable at the time of maturity will be on the basis of amount of premium paid+ bonus declared from time to time. It is interesting to note that the company allowed a bonus of 0.75% PA on the amount they receive from you. If you forget to pay the premium in time, they charge you over due interest of 12% PA.I would request you not to invest your hard earned money on HDFC Life insurance as they are totally a bunch of cheaters and arrogant
$  http://www.mouthshut.com/sundarramvs  Sundara Raman V S  53  Chennai, Tamil NaduF  http://www.mouthshut.com/review/HDFC-Life-Insurance-review-qtqsnrsmqlmï  Agent convinced me of a very good return about this policy.  He mentioned about 12% return on the investment.  Hence I have taken a policy with 5 years plan.  Yearly EMI of 30K.  Finally the Policy bond has arrived and I understood that I will not be getting the full money which I paid as premium during the maturity.I have paid full 5 EMI's and awaiting Nov for maturity.  I called up customer care and found that I will get back only 1,10,000+ Bonus(which is accrued till date only 4K).This is a cheating from such a big insurance firm.  Please do not take any policy from HDFC life.  Seems like they have similar approach.You can deposit your money in FD and you will get your full money back including the interest of 9%.HDFC life are cheaters.
'  http://www.mouthshut.com/sandeshpoojari  Sandesh PoojariF  http://www.mouthshut.com/review/HDFC-Life-Insurance-review-mqsmptplplm¢  Dont buy any policy from HDFC its a fraud company. I have invested in their suvidha plan for 5 years and now they dont want to give my money back. If you wnat to be safe dont invest in HDFC its the biggest fraud company. I was in India when I have invested now I'm in US they said unless you dont come to India we will not pay you not even to your family.If you still want to invest good luck to you and your family.
(  http://www.mouthshut.com/msdhuliawala167  Mustafa Dhuliawala  32
  Mumbai, IndiaF  http://www.mouthshut.com/review/HDFC-Life-Insurance-review-ssrsmrrsolmÅ  Hi,I bought a online policy click2invest on 23rd of march, while buying the policy I selected for 5 years premium payment terms, but upon submission I realized its showing 20 years for premium paying terms also.I have tried reaching the customer support to update this through mail and phone also, but they are simply ignoring and wasting my time so the policy lock in period is over.Can you please help me in this asap.my policy no. is 18328071Thanks
"  http://www.mouthshut.com/shk161455  Karan KF  http://www.mouthshut.com/review/HDFC-Life-Insurance-review-rlsolmnsolm”  First of all the tagline of HDFC life should be'Kuch bhi ho sakta hai' instead of'Sar utha ke Jiyo'.I have taken policy number 17814139 from HDFC Life. The experience of policy issuance has been described by me in another review which users can view under'Clueless staff non existent processes'.I thought the ordeal was over after policy issuance but this company refuses to let its policyholders live in peace. Today I got a shock of my life when I came to know utterly by chance that my policy was lapsed due to so called non payment of premium.(I have monthly mode of premium payment and my monthly premiums are duly debited from my bank account). I came to know this when I had logged into my account on HDFC portal. I had no prior intimations or communication from HDFC on this matter at<     any stage.When I called their call centre to know what had happened I came to know that after I had applied for the policy online there was a change in service tax rates and hence there was a difference in premium which I had paid at the time of application and premium due after change in tax rates. To my utter astonishment the amount of this difference in premium is Rs 4. Yes thats correct RS FOUR only.I am at total loss of words how to react to this situation. I just cannot fathom the utter lack of common sense and seriousness on part of this company which bears a brand name in India. Can you imagine my policy of Rs 50 lakhs lapsed unilaterally without any intimations for non payment of Rs FOUR? And apparently this shortage has been outstanding for six months now. During that entire time these geniuses did not have the time or the wits to communicate to me that I need to clear this shortage. They are least bothered if the policy is lapsed for such a frivolous reason.So if I die in this time these people will not have any hesitation to deny my claim of Rs 50 lakhs because I have not paid them Rs 4. I dont know whether to laugh or cry at this.Am I supposed to dream up that I owe these idiots 4 rs? Is it my responsibility to know if there is change in tax rates and consequent change in premium? And is it my responsibility to find out if I owe them premium? And do these idiots have no responsibility to inform me of this even once during the entire past six months?It just dose not end here. My monthly premium for March 2016 has got debited from my bank account even though the status of my policy is lapsed!   Have you ever heard of such absurdity? The company on the one hand collects premium from me. Then lapses my policy saying that I am not paying my premium. Then refuses to respond to my emails.Do they think they own policyholders or what and that they can do whatever comes to their mind and they will not answer any questions posed to them?If there is one sensible person working in HDFC Life, I urge that person to take cognizance of utter chaos and sheer drunkenness with which things happen in this company.At this rate I will not be surprised if these people tell my nominees at the time of claim that they do no have any record of my policy in their system. It is every bit possible with HDFC Life.If this was comedy show or a movie, it will break all records at the box office for sure.
   http://www.mouthshut.com/Kvp2901  Kaustubh  35  PuneF  http://www.mouthshut.com/review/HDFC-Life-Insurance-review-nnstotspolm+  H i   s i r &   w h y   a r e   y o u   a d v a n c i n g   t h i s   i t e m .   I   m   e n c o u n t e r i n g   m o s t   n o t i c e a b l y   a w f u l   a d m i n i s t r a t i o n   b y   h d f c   l i f e .   I   h a v e   o b t a i n e d   o n l i n e   e   t e r m   o n   f o u r t e e n t h   J a n   2 0 1 6   a n d   t i l l   d a t e   I   d i d n ' t   g o t   a n y   r e p o r t .   I   h a v e   e x p e r i e n c e d   n u m e r o u s   t h e r a p e u t i c   t e s t .   I   h a v e   s e n t   n u m e r o u s   q u e s t i o n n a i r e   a n d   t r a n s f e r r e d   m y   e v e r y t h i n g   i n d i v i d u a l   t h e r a p e u t i c   r e p o r t s   y e t   t i l l   d a t e   I   d i d n ' t   g o t   m y   s t r a t e g y   r e c o r d s .   I   t o o k   f o l l o w   u p   o r d i n a r i l y   h o w e v e r   i t s   o f   n o   u t i l i z a t i o n .   I   g e t s   a n s w e r   a s . u   w i l l   g e t   y o u   a r r a n g e m e n t   i s s u e d   i n s i d e   o f   5   o r   7   d a y s &   . y e t   a t   t h e   s a m e   t i m e   I   a m   t r y i n g   f o r   s a m e .   T h e   m o s t   n o t i c e a b l y   a w f u l   a d m i n i s t r a t i o n   I   m   c o n f r o n t i n g   i n   m y   l i f e &   . i   m   s t r e s s e d   t h a t   w h a t   w i l l   h a p p e n   w h e n   t i m e   d e s i r e   c l a i m   s e t t l e m e n t &   I   m   n o t   c e r t a i n   t h a t   m y   c h o s e n   o n e   w i l l   g e t   a g g r e g a t e   g u a r a n t e e d   o r   n o t . F i n a l l y   I   a s k   t h e m   c a n c e l   i t . 
 !  http://www.mouthshut.com/dasmercy$  Victoria Cheedi Georgedevadas Cheedi  29  Female
  VisakhapatnamF  http://www.mouthshut.com/review/HDFC-Life-Insurance-review-loumpnlpolm¹  HDFC extra security is my decision when I pick their administration. They have extremely decent plans administrations which suits my need. Their online administration alongside the portable application administration is so helpful to utilize and have important data. There live backing of costumer consideration is a decent step which can be come to either by visit or accessible if the need arises. Online administration gives picking and selecting any arrangements and paying for the same alongside the month to month premium installments additionally are exceptionally decent administrations to have. In this way, since my everything work can be done by means of online I lean toward HDFC administration. For all I without a doubt prescribe the Co since they are better than average. I pick Health Insurance Plans and Policies as it gave an assortment of Health Insurance Plans and Mediclaim Policies that offer budgetary security to meet wellbeing
#  http://www.mouthshut.com/dipalis186
  Dipali Shinde  26  mumbaiF  http://www.mouthshut.com/review/HDFC-Life-Insurance-review-pqmsnosoolmt  With the most trusty Brand name and best protection alternatives and adroit utilizes with information HDFC life coverage is my decision when I pick their administration. They have exceptionally decent plans administrations which suits my need. Their online administration alongside the portable application administration is so helpful to utilize and have important data. There live backing of costumer consideration is a decent step which can be come to either by visit or accessible if the need arises. Online administration gives picking and selecting any arrangements and paying for the same alongside the month to month premium installments likewise are extremely decent administrations to have. Therefore, since my everything work can be done by means of online I incline toward HDFC administration. For all I without a doubt suggest the Co since they are better than average.
"  http://www.mouthshut.com/mjangalwaF  http://www.mouthshut.com/review/HDFC-Life-Insurance-review-moluqsqoolmh  I had very bad exp with HDFC for the Personal loans or insurance.I took a personal loan from HDFC SLIC 3 years ago from their branch. I did not take from any third party person. Even the representatives appointed by the bank are giving false information. They did not gave proper information While taking the loan After  years when I requested for full payment of my loan they said that you have to pay  first five years by EMI after that you can do full payment. I was shocked to hear that since the person from whom I took the loan did not inform me about this.please take proper information before u take a loan
       »
Ì       
     d          ü©ñÒMbP?_    €         %   ÿ                 *    +    ‚               &P    &Fƒ   „    &  333333Ó?'  333333Ó?(  …ëQ¸…ã?)  ®Gáz®×?¡ "    d    ƒ ,,š™™™™™¹?š™™™™™¹?     Ý        c              ÿ       ý 
          ý 
        ý 
        ý 
        ý 
        ý 
        ý 
             ÿ       ý 
        ý 
       ý 
           ý 

   ý 
       ý 
       ý 

        ÿ       ý 
        ý 
       ý 
       ý 
       ý 
       ý 
       ý 
            ÿ       ý 
        ý 
       ý 
       ý 
       ý 
       ý 
       ý 
            ÿ       ý 
        ý 
       ý 
       ý 
       ý 
       ý 
       ý 
            ÿ       ý 
        ý 
       ý 
        ý 
    !   ý 
       ý 
       ý 
    "        ÿ       ý 
     #   ý 
    $   ý 
    %   ý 
    &   ý 
    '   ý 
       ý 
    (        ÿ       ý 
     )   ý 
    *   ý 
    +   ý 
    ,   ý 
       ý 
       ý 
            ÿ       ý 
     -   ý 
    .   ý 
    /   ý 
    0   ý 
    1   ý 
       ý 
    2           ÿ       ý 
        3   ý 
       4   ý 
       5   ý 
       6   ý 
          ý 
          ý 

    ÿ       ý 

    7   ý 

   8   ý 

   9   ý 

   :   ý 

   ;   ý 

      ý 

   <        ÿ       ý 
     =   ý 
    >   ý 
    ?   ý 
    @   ý 
    A   ý 
    B   ý 
    C        ÿ       ý 
     D   ý 
    E   ý 
    F   ý 
    G   ý 
    H   ý 
    B   ý 
    I    
    ÿ       ý 

    J   ý 

   K   ý 

   L   ý 

      ý 

      ý 

      ý 

           ÿ       ý 
     M   ý 
    N   ý 
    O   ý 
    P   ý 
    Q   ý 
       ý 
    R        ÿ       ý 
     S   ý 
    T   ý 
    U   ý 
    V   ý 
       ý 
       ý 
    W        ÿ       ý 
     X   ý 
    Y   ý 
    Z   ý 
    [   ý 
    \   ý 
       ý 
    ]        ÿ       ý 
     ^   ý 
    _   ý 
    `   ý 
    a   ý 
       ý 
       ý 
            ÿ       ý 
     b   ý 
    c   ý 
    d   ý 
    e   ý 
    f   ý 
       ý 
    g        ÿ       ý 
     h   ý 
    i   ý 
    j   ý 
    k   ý 
       ý 
       ý 
    l        ÿ       ý 
     m   ý 
    n   ý 
    o   ý 
    p   ý 
    \   ý 
       ý 
    q   > ¶    @           


                                                             !   "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   -   .   /   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   þÿÿÿýÿÿÿþÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿR o o t   E n t r y                                              ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                               À‹iµ   &Òþÿÿÿ        W o r k b o o k                                                  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                         p                                                                         ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                    þÿÿÿ                                                                           ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                    þÿÿÿ
```

Comment: You need to post your actual csv, it sounds like the separator is not a comma which is the default, is it tab or space separated?

Comment: I have opened csv in text format, and putting it here.

Comment: Please find above

Comment: it looks like you have unicode encoded file but what is the separator here? it looks like it's either tab or double space separated. How was this file created?

Comment: hmmm. I guessed that, this was created using BeautifulSoup in python. saved as csv.

Comment: Currently this file is almost unusable, you need to clean the file significantly prior to trying to load it using pandas

Comment: yes.. I know, this is why the question. I need to use the same file. manually when I just open it and saving as csv (Without doing any other changes), it is found that file size reduces and it become usable.

Comment: Sorry but your file is garbage, I can't find any combination of params to `read_csv` to read this file. You need to go back and clean the creation of the file